# Does it matter in which order I set the action in CSS definitions?

Tags: css

This might be a *silly* question, but i haven't managed to find out if there is a difference between these two CSS definitions:

```
div:hover.item {}
div.item:hover {}
```

Or... is the behavior the same for both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pseudo selectors such as :hover, :link, etc. come last

see http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp:

> The syntax of pseudo-classes:
>
> ```
> selector:pseudo-class {property:value;}
> ```
>
> CSS classes can also be used with
>   pseudo-classes:
>
> ```
> selector.class:pseudo-class {property:value;}
> ```